# Running script from .desktop file yields different result than from terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, xfce

When running the following script from a .desktop file the output is different than if run from the terminal. I would like it to run as it does in the terminal. My desktop enviroment is Xubuntu.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo protonvpn c --cc CZ
read -p 'Mount Encrypted Files? [ y/n ] ' encryptedmount
case $encryptedmount in
    [Yy]* ) veracrypt -t -k "" --pim=0 --protect-hidden=no /media/peterthegreat/Main_Data/Files /media/veracrypt1; break;;
    [Nn]* ) ;;
esac
cd /home/peterthegreat
tilix --session=~/Documents/Start_Up/TilixSetup.json -e & disown
```

The main differences are two:

- Tilix terminal does not open
- VPN breaks internet connection(Browser does not work)

Below is the .desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=StartUp
Type=Application
Exec=home/peterthegreat/Documents/Start_Up/StartUp.sh
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=true
```

Thanks

Comment: I know nothing about .desktop files. Is the working directory `/`? My point is `Exec=home/…` uses a relative path. How about `Exec=/home/…`?

Comment: The issue is still the same nevertheless I will leave it changed.

Comment: I have found that the $PATH variable is different if running the script from .desktop than from the terminal.

Comment: xfce4-terminal --command="/home/peterthegreat/Documents/Start_Up/StartUp.sh"
has the same effect as the .desktop file

Comment: I know this is an old topic, but I'm facing a similar situation. Did you eventually manage to resolve it?